# Extend line (utility-water) to polygon (building)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, line, snapping, extend

I have several thousand water lines that need to simply be extended to the edge of the nearest building. Some of my lines do touch or intersect the buildings and some don't. They are ranging from a few inches up to 50 feet from the edge. Is there a way to select the lines that aren't touching or intersecting a building and extend them so that they do touch or intersect a building? [image]

Comment: ArcMap 10.2.2. I can easily manually extend each line one by one but with thousands it would take forever. I've tried several tools such as "snap and extend" and have come up short.

Comment: @Rome3212 please review [topology](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-topology/geodatabase-topology-rules-and-topology-error-fixes.htm) in arcgis. It is available under standard license. You may use the `Must not have dangles` rule, and fix errors with extend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to Extend Lines to your Building Edge you must convert Building Polygons to Lines and Append the Line feature class. Select-by-Location Lines that Intersect Buildings, reverse Selection, Extend 50.